# how to avoid checkbox when we press space bar in tree control?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having a tree control where initially I had set it style in OnInitDialog as follows,

```
BOOL OnInitDialog()
{

  CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();
//Setting Treecontrol with TVS_CHECKBOXES style

  HWND m_hTreeWnd = ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd,IDC_TREE);
  DWORD dwStyle =  GetWindowLong(m_hTreeWnd,GWL_STYLE);
  dwStyle |= (TVS_CHECKBOXES);
  SetWindowLongPtr(m_hTreeWnd,GWL_STYLE,dwStyle);//CTreeCtrl m_hTreeWnd;



//Now I had initialized the tree control and I am want only few items of the tree to have 
  //checkboxes,In order to achieve that I did it as follows(Removing checkboxes where not required)

  tvInsertItem.hParent = NULL;
  tvInsertItem.hInsertAfter = TVI_ROOT;
  tvInsertItem.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT|TVIF_IMAGE|TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
  tvInsertItem.item.pszText = L"Name"
  hParentItemHandle = m_TreeCtrl.InsertItem(&tvInsertItem);

  //Removal of checkboxes for the above item
  tvItem.hItem = hParentItemHandle;
  tvItem.mask = TVIF_TEXT|TVIF_STATE|TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
  tvItem.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
  tvItem.state = 0;
  tvItem.pszText = szCommonModel;
  m_TreeCtrl.SetItem(&tvItem);


}
```

Everything is fine I removed checkbox in which ever the node it is not required.And having checkbox where they are required.

All of a sudden I noticed this issue i.e, after selecting an item in the tree control which does not have checkbox ,now if
I press "space bar"then a checkbox is getting append to that item.

I want avoid the checkbox when I press space bar.
To avoid checkbox I tried this but did not work.

```
BOOL CTreeControlDlg::OnTvnItemChangingTree(UINT i,NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMTVITEMCHANGE *pNMTVItemChange = reinterpret_cast<NMTVITEMCHANGE *>(pNMHDR);

    HTREEITEM hTree = pNMTVItemChange->hItem;
    UINT ChangItem = pNMTVItemChange->uStateNew;
    UINT ChangItem1 = pNMTVItemChange->uStateOld;
    UINT ItemState = m_TreeCtrl.GetItemState(hTree, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
    if(98 == ItemState)//98 is the thing I observed while debugging this is not correct I know.
        return FALSE;


    return TRUE;
}
```

I am bit confused how do we get the state image mask TVIS_STATEIMGAEMASK and how do we make that check whether the item has this mask or not .

Can anyone please suggest me a way to acheive this.

Comment: Handle `TVN_ITEMCHANGING` notification, check whether the state change involves `TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK` and whether the item affected is the one you don't want checkbox on. Return `FALSE` to prevent the change.

Comment: As you suggested I tried with TVN_ITEMCHANGING and modified my post according to that.My doubt is how do we check the state change involves TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK and how do we check whether the item is affected or not.I am a newbie to MFC. Can you please let me know  with an example how do we do this if possible :)

Comment: `TVN_ITEMCHANGING` comes with `NMTVITEMCHANGE` structure, complete with `uStateNew` and `uStateOld` fields (cast `pNMHDR` pointer to `NMTVITEMCHANGE*`).